# Using `InterfaceController` logic for `ComplicationController'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit, watchos-2

I'm doing an Apple Watch **App**, with a **Complication**.

I've got the **WatchKit App part working great** with this `Ev` class...

```
class Ev {
    var evTColor:String
    var evMatch:String

    init(dataDictionary:Dictionary<String,String>) {
        evTColor = dataDictionary["TColor"]!
        evMatch = dataDictionary["Match"]!
    }

    class func newEv(dataDictionary:Dictionary<String,String>) -> Ev {
        return Ev(dataDictionary: dataDictionary)
    }

}
```

... and this `InterfaceController`

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let tColorValue = userInfo["TColor"] as? String, let matchValue = userInfo["Match"] as? String {

        receivedData.append(["TColor" : tColorValue , "Match" : matchValue])
        evs.append(Ev(dataDictionary: ["TColor" : tColorValue , "Match" : matchValue]))

        doTable()

    } else {
        print("tColorValue and matchValue are not same as dictionary value")
    }

}


func doTable() {

    self.rowTable.setNumberOfRows(self.evs.count, withRowType: "rows")

    for (index, evt) in evs.enumerate() {

        if let row = rowTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as? TableRowController {

            row.mLabel.setText(evt.evMatch)
            row.cGroup.setBackgroundColor(colorWithHexString(evt.evTColor))

        } else {
            print("nope")
        }
    }

}
```

I'm having a **hard time getting the same sort of thing to work in my Complication**, any ideas?

I'm not sure if I can just use the same `Ev` code for my `ExtensionDelegate`, and then what exactly to put in my `ComplicationController`.

If I use the same `Ev` code in my `ExtensionDelegate` I'm getting a *fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer init()*.

And in my `ComplicationController` I'm not sure how to go about best using the data I already have from `InterfaceController` to fill out the `getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication` &`getTimelineEntriesForComplication` methods in `ComplicationController`.

Will post any extra code as needed, thanks!

**EDIT:**
Per a question, my data comes from CloudKit to the iPhone App (which I then pass to the Watch App via `WCSession`, so my problem is accessing that data in my Watch App for my Complication)

Comment: Where is your data coming from? A database? A remote API?

Comment: CloudKit supplies the data to the iPhone app, then I pass that data to the Watch App.  And that part works great, I just need to access the data my Watch App has in order to fill out the complication ya know? (I'll note the CloudKit part in my question now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having your `InterfaceController` implement and receive the `WCSession` messages, I would set up a singleton class that receives those messages instead. That class can parse and organize your user info data from the `WCSession`. That singleton class can/will be accessible in your `ComplicationController` and your `InterfaceController`

Singletons are fairly easy to setup in swift:

```
class DataManager : WCSessionDelegate {
    // This is how you create a singleton
    static let sharedInstance = DataManager()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        if WCSession.isSupported() {
            self.watchConnectivitySession?.delegate = self
            self.watchConnectivitySession?.activateSession()
        }
    }

    // This is where you would store your `Ev`s once fetched
    var dataObjects = [Ev]()

    // This is the method that would fetch them for you
    func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {
        //parse your userInfoDictionary
        self.dataObjects = evs
    }
}
```

Then in your `InterfaceController` you can reference it using `DataManager.sharedInstance.dataObjects` to build your `InterfaceController` or `ComplicationsController`

The idea with a singleton is that you have a one global reference. DataManager only gets instantiated once and only once.

Comment: Is that sort of what I already have going on with `Ev` or no?

Comment: The `Ev` appears to be just a model object. Your singleton object will contain a collection of `Ev` objects that you can use to build your `InterfaceController` as well as your `ComplicationController`. The singleton will also receive the `WCSession` messages and create the `Ev` objects

Comment: I know that's a pretty regular thing, but I've never done it, so if you have any articles on using it with watchOS 2 that would be greatly appreciated! Then I can give it a go.  I was basically trying to use `ExtensionDelegate` as a singleton, and was having a hard time figuring out how that should look ya know

Comment: @SRMR I updated my answer, I hope those fixes help you. Let me what what you don't understand

Comment: Cool thanks for the details, I like where this is going!  A couple questions.  I get an error on `static sharedInstance = DataManager()`, any ideas? I believe what I do to “fetch” the `Ev`s is my `WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo` function, so I’m not sure how I’d get that inside of the `getDataObjects` function, do you know what would be best? To trigger `DataManager.sharedInstance.getDataObjects()` in my `InterfaceController` is it best to put that in `awakeWithContext` or something else?

Comment: I omitted an important `let` it now states `static let sharedInstance = DataManager()`

Comment: I updated the DataManager to implement the `WCSessionDelegate` so when you get a user info dictionary you can set the `dataObjects` array.

Comment: Yes, You can add that the awakeWithContext, that's fine

Comment: So I had the `didReceiveUserInfo` code working, and obviously I can just move it over to the Singleton, but just wondering what the difference between that and `getDataObjects` is? Or does the `didReceiveUserInfo` code I have look not quite enough or something.

Comment: No user info should be enough

Comment: Cool cool, so a problem I’ve run into is if `didReceiveUserInfo` is in a separate file from `doTable`, the `doTable` runs before `didReceiveUserInfo` which gives me a blank table.  Whats your suggestion on that from the code I have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103554/discussion-between-kyle-redfearn-and-srmr).

Comment: (Posted my code in the chat with a follow up question)

Comment: (updated my code and have just one small problem with how I must have set up my NSNotification if you can take a peek.  Thanks!)

Comment: Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I suggest you post new questions on SO for the new problems you are running into. I can't help you with every problem you encounter

Comment: I did post a new question today, thanks for the advice Kyle (+resolved w/bounty appreciated)